# Setting upload_tmp_dir ignored in PHP

Tags: php, nginx, file-upload, fpm

I'm trying to upload a file via nginx/php-fpm (php 7)

I don't want to upload the files to be uploaded in tmp (before moving them), so  I changed the upload_tmp_dir to point to another directory:

```
/media/test/tmpUpload
```

The problem is that the file is still uploaded to /tmp

I'm setting the new value in my vhost

```
location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    #other parameters
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php72-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME         $host;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "short_open_tag=Off

    post_max_size = 400M
    upload_max_filesize = 400M
    upload_tmp_dir = /media/test/tmpUpload
    ";
}
```

To check settings, in my php upload script, here I added the following debugging code

```
echo ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');
```

and

```
var_dump($_FILES['file']);
```

Here is the output when uploading a file

```
/media/test/tmpUpload

array(5) 
{
  ["name"]=>
  string(51) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pdf"
  ["type"]=>
  string(15) "application/pdf"
  ["tmp_name"]=>
  string(14) "/tmp/phpe2mutM"
  ["error"]=>
  int(0)
  ["size"]=>
  int(774476)
}
```

So PHP knows about the setting, but seems to ignore it.  Am I missing something?

Comment: 1. Does the folder /media/test/tmpUpload exist ? 2. Is the folder /media/test/tmpUpload writable by the user running the PHP FPM ? 3. Is open_basedir active and is the /media/test/tmpUpload inside ? Those 3 would be the first things to check that come to my mind. If the /media/test/tmpUpload is not writable/acessible, PHP will continue to use the system default dir...

Comment: @Zimmi:  1. Yes that folder exists. However, even if I specify a folder that does NOT exists, the file is still uploaded and then moved without error. 2. Yes,the php-fpm user has rwx rights to that folder. 3. open_basedir is empty

Comment: @Zimmi: Weird, it looks like it's working now.. I just restarted 'again' nginx et php-fpm processes and it worked. Thanks for your help anyway, and good to know that it won't throw any error if the tmp upload dir is not writeable or does not exists